# Why does google sheet give the error " the range name specified isn't valid " when I am trying to name the cell as c?

Tags: google-sheets

Why does google sheet give the error " the range name specified isn't valid. I am trying to name the cell c, because it contains the value of speed  of light.
As far as i know, it does not break any of the rules for naming a named range.

[image]

You can see from the named range panel on the right, that i have named the 2 nearby cells as d and v without any problem, so why is it not accepting c ?
You can also see the list of all the named ranges that i have defined, and i have not defined any other cell as c, so there is no question of the name overlapping with that of any other cell .

Comment: Next to the error message there is a ?. Click on it and read the help about the error message. Anyway, it looks that this can only be answered by Google, what might make this question off-topic.

Comment: @Rubén That ? symbol just links to the generic support page https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175 which just gives the usual help document for this function.

Comment: If you think that help article is not useful, please submit your feedback directly to Google. At the bottom of the article there are links and buttons to do that.

Comment: @Rubén That's the first thing i did :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is not possible to name the range "C". I have checked that the name "R" cannot be assigned to the range either.
The [help article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) doesn't say anything about this.